# User existing in Users folder, but not visible when Get-LocalUser in PowerShell or in Settings page

Tags: windows-10

In my Users folder I have multiple users subfolders. 
There is admin - which indeed is account with administrator's privileges. 
And there is matt - regular account.

I can log in to both of them and when I go to C:\Users I can see both of them.

On any of them if I use Get-LocalUser I can't see matt account.

I would like to change matt's account to admin type. The thing is that, admin and matt accounts are on different domains. Is is to possible to change matt's account in this case?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2):

[`Get-LocalUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) on Microsoft Docs:

> The Get-LocalUser cmdlet gets local user accounts. This cmdlet gets default built-in user accounts, local user accounts that you created, and local accounts that you connected to Microsoft accounts.

You won't see domain joined accounts that logged into your machine at some point using this command.

It's still possible to add domain accounts to local security groups like the admin group.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You can go to **computer Management** > **Local Users and Groups** > **Groups** - open **Administrators** and **add** any user there.